# Query where using the name of key object

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in postgresql of type JSON in this column i have this data:

```
["row1", {
    "date": "05/30/2019",
    "name": "JOSH",
    "discount": "160.00"
}, {
    "date": "04/30/2019",
    "name": "JOSH",
    "discount": "170.00"
}, {
    "date": "03/30/2019",
    "name": "JOSH",
    "discount": "79.00"
}, "row2", {
    "date": "05/30/2019",
    "name": "MARIO",
    "discount": "110.00"
}, {
    "date": "04/30/2019",
    "name": "MARIO",
    "discount": "101.00"
}, {
    "date": "03/30/2019",
    "name": "MARIO",
    "discount": "98.00"
}]
```

I need extract data in base to key name 'row1' and 'row2' for this example data.

I have already tried the following sentences without success:

```sql
select data->>'row1' from discounts;

SELECT *
FROM   discounts
WHERE  json_arr_record_keys(data->'row1');

SELECT *
FROM   discounts
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   json_array_elements(data->'row1') elem

   );
```

for now always display empty result, i need by example extract 'row1'

```
{
    "date": "05/30/2019",
    "name": "JOSH",
    "discount": "160.00"
}, {
    "date": "04/30/2019",
    "name": "JOSH",
    "discount": "170.00"
}, {
    "date": "03/30/2019",
    "name": "JOSH",
    "discount": "79.00"
}
```

Comment: I don't think your JSON is formatted correctly for what you want to do. The example you posted is an array that contains the values `row1`, `row2` and some objects. You need to format you json like `{"row1": [{...}, {...}], "row2": [{...}, {...}], ...`

Comment: Why JSON in the first place? This looks like data that could easily (and more efficiently) be stored in a properly normalized table

Comment: "row1" or "row2" is not an key

Comment: use json because the fields are variable, now they are 3 could be 4 or 2.